# How to find cluster in 1D dataset using R

Tags: r

I have 1D data (with only one variable), I want to get 3 clusters from this variable. My data set looks something like this:

[image]

I was trying to get clusters with k-means but I always get an error.

```
d_frame <- df
d_frame <- scale(d_frame)
head(d_frame)
    
kmeans2 <- kmeans(d_frame, centers = 3, nstart = 25)
str(kmeans2)

#vizalni prkaz
fviz_cluster(kmeans2, data = d_frame)
```

Does anyone know hot can I get three clusters in 1D dataset?

Thank you for help

Comment: Typically we arrange data with variables as columns and observations as rows. The way your data is set up most modeling functions will interpret at as 1 observation each of many variables. It would also help to mention if order matters at all in your data.

Comment: I tried to arrange data with variables as columns.  When I try to run "fviz_cluster(kmeans2, data = d_frame)" the error says  "The dimension of the data < 2! No plot".

Comment: So sounds like you successfully fit the k-means, you just can't visualize it. What does `kmeans2` or `summarize(kmeans2)` show?

Comment: @GregorThomas kmenas2 shows `K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 1, 9, 3

Cluster means:
        [,1]
1 -2.3481466
2  0.5738151
3 -0.9387298

Clustering vector:
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 1

Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 0.0000000 0.6168530 0.2623398
 (between_SS / total_SS =  92.7 %)

Available components:

[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss" "betweenss"    "size"         "iter"        
[9] "ifault"`

Comment: oh yeah I found the mistake! It works thank you @GregorThomas

Answer (score 0):

Before you start nake sure that you arrange data with variables as columns and observations as rows.

```
    #Read data from CSV
            df <- read.csv("clustering.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", row.names = 1)
    #show imported data
            df
    #calculate
            d_frame <- df
            d_frame <- scale(d_frame)
            head(d_frame)
            
            
    #select number of centers
            kmeans2 <- kmeans(d_frame, centers = 3, nstart = 25)
            str(kmeans2)
            
    #show results
            kmeans2
```